# JavaScript: Take an index of an item in an array, and figure out what the index of the same item would be if the array were reversed?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**The Setup**

I have an array of objects called Elements. They are visually laid out like layers in a photoshop document. I have stripped out most of the data from each element for brevity. But the data changes for each element, because they are all different.

```
elements = [
    {
        name: 'First Piece',
    },
    {
        name: 'Second',
    },
    {
        name: 'Third', 
    },
    {
        name: 'Fourth', // is selected
    },
    {
        name: 'Fifth',
    },
]
```

I keep track of which element is selected in an object using the index of the selected item. I use the index because it is always available to me at any given time or place the elements are represented. The object looks like this, sans the non relevant data:

```
selected = {
    element: 3,
}
```

This all works great.

**The Problem**

The problem lies in what could be considered my Layers panel. When the elements are on the 'canvas', they are in the correct order with each element having a higher z-index. But in the layers panel, I have to reverse the array so that it visually makes sense. So the 'Fifth' element is on top.

The problem is when I need to take the value of selected, and apply it to the reversed elements array.

```
elementsReversed = [
    {
        name: 'Fifth',
    },
    {
        name: 'Fourth',   // this should be selected
    },
    {
        name: 'Third',
    },
    {
        name: 'Second',   // would be selected
    },
    {
        name: 'First Piece',
    },
]
```

I can't use .findIndex() because the names could be set to the same value (for a reason) and there aren't really other attributes I could use to search through a reversed array and find the index that way. I am trying to avoid adding another key/value pair to my objects like an ID.

Is there a way to do this? Am I just being a dum dum?

Thank you.

Comment: I would think the obvious answer would be to add an id attribute to the object itself, and you can `const item3 = arr.find(e => e.id == 3)` however if the arr is reversed you could just say the new index is `arr.length - oldIndex - 1` i.e. arr of 5, index 3 reversed would be 5 - 3 - 1 or 1.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't wrap my head around that math. Works great.

Comment: I’d be curious to know how you are drawing your elements. If it’s using a loop you can render them last index to first just by changing the loop `for (let i=array.length - 1; i <= 0; i—)` same with other loops. Now the array stays the same but they render opposite of  `for (let i=0; i < array.length; I++)`. Don’t know your code though.

Comment: It's a Svelte app, so the elements are being drawn with {#each} blocks. I don't think you can reverse the each blocks. I have a drag and drop tool involved that re-orders every thing and that complicates things.